# How to join two event streams on a common event property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactive-programming, rxjs, xstream

Consider the following two event streams. Every event has a timestamp/ts and value property.

[image: Input stream]

I want to combine these two streams where the events have the same timestamps, into a resulting stream with an applied transformation of the value. If one stream is missing one timestamp (such as the yellow `ts=3` in the example below), that timestamp should be disregarded.

[image]

Would like to solve the problem using a reactive programming library such as [xstream](https://github.com/staltz/xstream) or [rxjs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS). I'm quite new to the concepts of reactive programming, but if someone has another suggestion I'm all ears. Thanks!

Comment: I just love your diagrams!! About your issue, it is difficult in general, I mean you need to see the whole stream to do your matching, unless you can guarantee ordering (i.e. timestamp increasing function of time, which means no values come out of order). Otherwise it maybe could be done using the `join` operator

Comment: Thanks :) We can probably assume that timestamps always comes in increasing order.

Comment: also would be nice if all the values had different timestamps

Comment: We can probably assume that too, all timestamps will be unique per input stream.

Comment: alright, got no time now to look at but I would try something with s1.join(s2, s1Val => s1.skipUntil(s2.value = s1Val), timer(0)) but that's just the back of my mind. The `join` function is pretty badly documented, but if you don't get any answer I can have a closer look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use combineLatest and pass only those combinations that have a matching timestamp. The other combinations are mapped to `null`, which you filter out later.

Here's the solution in xstream:

```
var streamOut = xs.combine(
  (a, b) => {
    if (a.ts === b.ts) {
      return {ts: a.ts, value: a.value + b.value};
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
  streamA, streamB
).filter(x => x !== null);
```

Check it running in JSBin: https://jsbin.com/saxawatuza/edit?js,console.

Comment: a non-related comment, Andre, the OP used the `xstream` tag, which is unrelated to the `xtream` streaming library. Would be nice to have a specific tag for that.

Comment: @user3743222 I agree